# How do I use a Vlookup command to select an entry in a combobox?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have been pouring over this code attempting to make it work for me, but I've hit the wall.  I would like to have a vlookup command pull from a textbox and automatically select a matching value from multiple comboboxes when the user presses a command button.

Here's my logic.

Excel 2010 > Userform > VBA

1)  User enters an alpha-numeric code into textbox "TxtDXCode".
2)  User presses button "CmdMap"
3)  Extract the left 3 characters from that textbox and assign them to a variable.
4)  Populate textbox "TxtDxCodeLeft3" with said variable (this is a redundant step, just so I have visual confirmation that the code works).
5)  Use value of textbox "TxtDxCodeLeft3" as search parameter for a vlookup command.
6)  Use vlookup to select a list item from pre-populated comboboxes "CboCMChapter" and "CboCMCode".

```
Private Sub CmdMap_Click()

'(((Extract left values from DX Code and Procedure Code strings to use in Vlookup.)))

    'Define variables
    Dim L1ResultDX As String
    Dim L1ResultProc As String
    Dim L2ResultProc As String
    Dim L3ResultProc As String

    'Assign values to variables
    L1ResultDX = Left(TxtDxCode, 3)
    L1ResultProc = Left(TxtProcCode, 1)
    L2ResultProc = Left(TxtProcCode, 2)
    L3ResultProc = Left(TxtProcCode, 3)

    'Extract first 3 characters from DX Code for Vlookup command
    Me.TxtDxCodeLeft3.Text = L1ResultDX

    'Validate TxtDXCode
    If TxtDxCode.TextLength < 6 Then
        MsgBox "Missing or invalid code. ", vbExclamation, "DX Code Entry"
        TxtDxCode.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

'(((Assign CM Codes & Chapters to comboboxes as result of Vlookup function.)))

    'Set CM combobox default value based on Vlookup results
    Me.CboCMChapter.Default = Application.VLookup(TxtDxCodeLeft3.Text, Worksheets("CM Chapters").Range("A3:B23,A26:A27,A29:A30"), 2, True)
    Me.CboCMCode.Default = Application.VLookup(TxtDxCodeLeft3.Text, Worksheets("CM Codes").Range("A3:B283"), 2, True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  The following lines of code are in the wrong format.

```
'CM combobox default value based on Vlookup results
    Me.CboCMChapter.Default = Application.VLookup(blah blah blah)
    Me.CboCMCode.Default = Application.VLookup(blah blah blah)
```

The correct format is:

```
'CM combobox default value based on Vlookup results
    Me.CboCMChapter.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(blah blah blah)
    Me.CboCMCode.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(blah blah blah)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not trying to put the value from the TxtDxCodeLeft3 and call it in a excel cell then use vlookup from there then the result would be called to the userform.

```
range("A1").value = TxtDxCodeLeft3.value 
cell A2 = vlookup(a1, range) - this will contain the lookup value for CboCMChapter
cell A3 = vlookup(a1, range) - this will contain the lookup value for CboCMCode

then call it again in the userform

CboCMChapter.value = range("a2").value
CboCMCode.value = range("a3").value
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Without me putting any thought into possible work-arounds, the quick answer is...because the user of the workbook has no say in its development.  The management chain above her is Excel illiterate and gets rather angry if we make any changes to the worksheets themselves.  As a result, I've tried to hide all the workings of this userform in the code where it won't impact nor be noticed by the management.

Comment: From your code @venjho, it looks as if I just need to set the .Value attribute (not the .Default attribute) of the combobox = to my vlookup result.  Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I too had the same problem a couple of months back. Decided to another sheet to lookup the results instead of trying to place it all in the vba code then hid and protected the sheet so no one can edit it.